# chapter change impact table of content title

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, titles, chapters

This is my first question on this site, I don't know if I can format code to display some latex example...

I am writing my PhD manuscript.

I wanted to get rid of the Chapter XX before my chapter title 
In order to have my chapter displayed like this : XX ChapterTitle

In order to achieve this I did

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\flushleft}{}{1em}{ \thechapter\hspace{1pt} }
```

Witch give me what I want.

But I notice it has a side effect
Now instead of "Content" being displayed in Table of content
I have "0.0 Content" which is odd and unprofessional

I tryed

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Content}
```

But that does not solve my problem. Which make sense because I believe the problem is not the name of the table of content but the fact it is considered as a chapter and I redefined the way to write chapter title...
If anyone could help me that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a simple remark about your code: `flushleft` is an environment. You should use `\raggedright`. Furthermore, `titlesec` defines new commands for that (`\filleft,filright,\filcenter`). I suspect it is because the standard commands may have unwanted side effects in this context, so it is certainly better to use the titlesec commands.

Second, you can define a different formatting for unnumbered chapter (or sections, ot …) with the `numberless` key. Last the  `hang` style is the default. Here is a code:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\filright}{\thechapter}{1em}{}

\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\filright}{}{0em}{}
```